# Lack of Intellisense option in Resharper

Tags: resharper

I have a problem and that is that Resharper is active for me but you are not working.

After a bit of research I went from the Intellisense menu to ReSharper
let me
But there was no Intellisense menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loXQP.png)

As you can see in the picture, there is no Intellisense menu.

```
What should I do now?
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have ReSharper enabled on the [Products & Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJP6B.png) options page. In general, if you have any issues with ReSharper it's better to ask on the dedicated [ReSharper support forum](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community).